# At my facebook instant article my domain is not approved what to do

Tags: facebook-instant-articles

I applied for facebook instant article from a page which is an old page but it rejected and my domain is listed on 'not approved domain' . and i couldn't appeal also so can we re-apply for instant article on this domain again or not?

Answer (score 0):

The terms and policies from this product were altered recently and you should review these:

- Confirm that you have an admin role on that Page. Another admin may
  have set up Instant Articles previously.
- Check in your Page's
  publishing tools to see if you already have access to Instant
  Articles. Your Page might violate the Monetization Eligibility
  Standards. [Review the standards](https://www.facebook.com/help/publisher/monetization-eligibility) to learn how to make your Page
  eligible for Instant Articles.
- Your Page might not meet our standards
  for having an established presence on Facebook.

If you applied to Instant Articles this month, maybe the stats on your site has changed for the next month time period. We have the standards measured monthly, so on next month your stats might have changed.